# Can we prove an open affine subscheme of a noetherian scheme is noetherian without Axiom of Choice?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, axiom-of-choice

I'm interested in proving basic results of algebraic geometry without Axiom of Choice.
As for why I think this is interesting, please see Pete L. Clark's answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22927/why-worry-about-the-axiom-of-choice).
To state my problem, I need some basic definitions.

**Definition 1**
A ring $A$ is called noetherian if every nonempty set of ideals of $A$ has a maximal element.

**Definition 2**
A scheme $X$ is called noetherian if it is a finite union of affine open subschemes Spec $A_i$, where each $A_i$ is noetherian.

**My Question**
Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme.
Let $U =$ Spec $A$ be a *nonempty* affine open subscheme of $X$.
Can we prove that $A$ is noetherian without Axiom of Choice?

**Remark**
I came up with this problem when I tried to solve [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163618/can-we-construct-cohomolgy-theory-on-noetherian-separated-schemes-without-axiom).

If the answer is negative, what conditions are needed to make it affirmative?
$X$ should be separated, of finite type over a noetherian ring, etc?

The usual proof uses the following fact.

Let $X =$ Spec $A$ be an affine scheme.
Suppose $X$ is a finite union of open affine subschemes Spec $A_{f_i}$, where each $A_{f_i}$ is noetherian. Then $A$ is noetherian.

To prove this, the usual proof uses the fact that the set $\{f_i\}$ generates $A$, which can be easily proved using Axiom of Choice.

**Remark 2**
The following observations might help.

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme.
Let $U =$ Spec $A$ be an affine open subscheme of $X$.

It can be proved without Axiom of Choice that the underlying topological space of $X$ is noetherian.
See my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712691/can-we-prove-that-a-quasi-compact-locally-noetherian-space-is-noetherian-without).

It is easy to prove withhout Axiom of Choice that every subspace of a noetherian topological space is noetherian.
Hence the underlying topological space of $U =$ Spec $A$ is noetherian.

See also my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681413/noetherianess-of-a-locally-noetherian-affine-scheme-without-axiom-of-choice).

Comment: I think you would get a better reception to questions like this if you included some discussion of how Choice is used in the standard proofs.

Comment: @EricWofsey The usual proof uses a fact that there exists a prime ideal containing a given proper ideal of a ring.

Comment: I mean other than the fact that the ascending chain condition implies the maximal condition, which needs a weak form of Axiom of Choice to prove it.

Comment: Please explain the reason for the downvote. Otherwise I cannot improve the question.

Comment: If $A$ is a (necessarily non-Noetherian) nonzero ring with no prime ideals, then $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is Noetherian (it can be covered by the affine open subscheme $\operatorname{Spec} 0$) even though $A$ is not.  It seems to me like what you really want to do is change the definition of "open cover" to require that (in the affine case) the set $\{f_i\}$ generates $A$, rather than just looking at points.  This formulation is much more natural in the absence of Choice, and I expect it makes the theory work as usual.

Comment: @EricWofsey I would like to know if we can prove that $A$ is noetherian without AC if Spec $A$ is a *nonempty* open subset of a noetherian scheme.

Comment: @EricWofsey At that point, it would seem that one should just switch to "pointless topology" and work with locales instead of topological spaces.

Comment: Emptiness of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is in no way essential to my counterexample.  For instance, you could replace $A$ with $A\times B$ for any Noetherian ring $B$.  I quite strongly think that you're asking the wrong question and, as Zhen suggested, you should be treating schemes as locales rather than as topological spaces.

Comment: @EricWofsey What exactly do you mean by the *wrong question*?

Comment: You seem to be interested in whether the general theory of Noetherian schemes can be developed as usual without assuming the Axiom of Choice.  I've shown that with your choice of definitions, it cannot.  However, I'm suggesting that instead of just accepting this negative answer, you should use a different definition (which is equivalent if you assume Choice) for which I believe you will get a positive answer.  This is similar to how in the absence of Choice, you are "asking the wrong questions" if you define "Noetherian ring" to mean "all ascending chains of ideals stabilize".

Comment: @EricWofsey [*I've shown that with your choice of definitions, it cannot.*]
Have you read my remark?
For example, what if $X$ is a separated scheme of finite type over a field?

Comment: What I am saying is that those are still the wrong questions.  You might come up with some set of hypotheses that allow you to still prove this theorem, but you will be able to get a more general and satisfying theory without needing special hypotheses if you instead just change your definitions.

Comment: As I mentioned before, this is analogous to needing to use the correct definition of "Noetherian" in the absence of Choice.  If you use the wrong definition, you can possibly still prove theorems if you add some extra hypotheses (for instance, that all your rings are countable), but it is better to instead just use the "right" definition from the start.

Comment: [*What I am saying is that those are still the wrong questions.*]
For example, let $X$ be a projective scheme over an algebraic number field.
I think this is a very concrete mathematical object.
I would be surprised if we cannot prove without AC that every affine open subscheme of $X$ is Spec of a noetherian ring.

Comment: @EricWofsey [*but you will be able to get a more general and satisfying theory without needing special hypotheses if you instead just change your definitions.*] My purpose is not to develop a general and satisfying theory. As I wrote I'm interested in proving basic results of algebraic geometry without AC. The reason was explained in Pete L. Clark's answer to the linked question. In short, a proof without AC is more constructive, hence it gives us more information about the problem.